# How to exclude special characters in a string using regular expressions in hive

Tags: regex, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I want to exclude periods(`.`) and braces (`(`,`)`).
However, decimal numbers should be left intact

So basically if the input is

> Hive supports subqueries only in the FROM clause (through Hive 0.12).
>   The subquery has to be given a name because every table in a FROM
>   clause must have a name. Columns in the subquery select list must have
>   unique names.

The output should be

> Hive supports subqueries only in the FROM clause through Hive 0.12 The
>   subquery has to be given a name because every table in a FROM clause
>   must have a name Columns in the subquery select list must have unique
>   names

Comment: Do you want to remove commas(`,`) also?

Comment: But there is no comma in this paragraph

Comment: No, there is no comma in this specific example but in the question you wrote `exclude periods , and braces `. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (select 'Hive supports subqueries only in the FROM clause (through Hive 0.12). The subquery has to be given a name because every table in a FROM clause must have a name. Columns in the subquery select list must have unique names.' as mycol)

select  regexp_replace(mycol,'(\\d+\\.\\d+)|[.()]','$1'),'\\((.*?)\\)'
from    t
```

> Hive supports subqueries only in the FROM clause through Hive 0.12 The
>   subquery has to be given a name because every table in a FROM clause
>   must have a name Columns in the subquery select list must have unique
>   names

Comment: Yes . I will get back to you . Let me learn this solution and check how it works ? :)