# Efficient way to extract value in quotation marks " in Hive with special characters column

Tags: regex, hive, special-characters, hiveql

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791225/how-to-exclude-special-characters-in-a-string-using-regular-expressions-in-hive) question. I have table in HDFS that includes table with specific column (string array) that somewhere in its records there are special characters.
I used regex in Hive for extracting the values in the first quotation mark (I use the `case` statement to detect if there is " - I regex, otherwise I return the column value as-is). However, most probably because of special characters there are skips and abnormality in the results. I would like to ask what is the most efficient way to solve it and how? At first phase to clean the column (by regex as while leaving the qoutation marks) and afterwards to use my regex. Or altenatively there is a way to use them both in one regex?

Comment: Avi, please add a data sample including requested result

Comment: The problem is that it is big data... and the vast majority of rows looks like normal ones. I can add a little example: dasdsa<here"abcd"...."fsdg" I need to extract only the abcd.